# How can I run this bash HEREDOC block as a non-root user?

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to write a `bash` script which

1. installs `git` then
2. creates a `.gitconfig` file and `cat`'s config text into it.

Because the first task requires *installing* git, the script needs to be run as root, however, I want to de-elevate the script to a regular user while creating and `cat`ing config text into the `.gitconfig` file.

heres what I have so far (I have removed extraneous content from script)

```sh
#! /bin/bash

apt-get install -y git

if [ ! -f /home/$admin_user/.gitconfig ]
then
    echo -e "${yellow}Creating .gitconfig file${normal}"
    sudo -s -u $admin_user <<EOF
        cat <<- DGC >> /home/$admin_user/.gitconfig
            [alias]
            lg1 = ..
            lg2 = ...
            lg3 = ...

            [user]
                email = server_admin@DO_droplet.com
                name = server_admin
            # 
            [push]
                default = simple
        DGC
    EOF
else
    echo -e "${yellow} gitconfig already exists - so I will not make any modifications${normal}"
fi
```

when I run this I get an error

> script.sh: line 782: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I think the error is being caused by the HEREDOCs?

I am open to the other suggestion other than using sudo and HEREDOC to de-elevate to `$admin_user` - I am just looking for a solution to creating the .gitconfig as `$admin_user` and not root

Comment: You cannot have any leading whitespace before the `EOF` delimiter.  If you absolutely require whitespace, you need to use `<<-EOF`with a dash, in which case leading tabs will be ignored; or maybe use `____________EOF` flush to the left margin which still visually resembles an indented delimiter.

Comment: d'oh! I should have seen that, yes that fixed it thanks @tripleee